# Indefinite Quadratic Forms and their Geometry

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, quadratic-forms, clifford-algebras

I'm looking for a book that would included an elementary introduction to the groups $O(p,q)$ and $SO(p,q)$ that would be suitable to an undergraduate with a background in Linear Algebra and Group Theory. Ideally, this would include an introduction to Clifford theory as well.